# Copy media gallery to another product

Tags: product, import, image

I want to copy the images of a product to another product.
I wrote the following script:

```
$mediaGallery = $anotherProduct->getMediaGallery();
$p->setMediaGallery(null);

Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

foreach($mediaGallery["images"] as $image) {
    $filePath = $importDir.$image["file"];
    if(file_exists($filePath) && !file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'import'.DS.'catalog'.DS.'product'.$image["file"])) {

        $p->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('small_image','thumbnail','image'), false, false)->save();

        $attributes = $p->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($p);
            $attributes['media_gallery']->getBackend()->updateImage($p, $image["file"], array('postion'=>$image['postion'],'postion_default'=>$image['postion_default'],'label'=>$image['label'],'label_default'=>$image['label_default'],'disabled'=>$image['disabled'],'disabled_default'=>$image['disabled_default']));
    }
}
```

There is exact one image in `$mediaGallery`.
The Script imports two entries (one is empty). The other entry is correct but the labels (for each store) are missing.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried dumping the `$mediaGallery["images"]` array to see if there is an empty one in there? If yes, just  do a `if($image["file"] !='')` after you start your foreach loop.

Comment: Yes, of course:
array(2) {
  ["images"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(8) {
      ["value_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["file"]=>
      string(12) "/3/_/3_0.jpg"
      ["label"]=>
      string(14) "Test"
      ["position"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["disabled"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["label_default"]=>
      string(14) "Test"
      ["position_default"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["disabled_default"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
  ["values"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

I think better get images by `$product->getMediaGalleryImages();`

And then foreach loop:

```
   $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
   foreach ($images as $image) {
       // Check if the file path exists
       if( $path = $image->getPath() ) {
           $anotherProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($path, array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false);
       }
   }
```